# using where statement with flatten custom dimension

Tags: google-bigquery

I've build the following query :

```
SELECT
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 10, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS postId,
  DATE(MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 4, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL))) WITHIN RECORD AS Datepublished,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 1, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Country,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 7, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Author,
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([storied-toolbox-145015:102152044.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
```

however I would like to be able to use a where statement based on one of the custom dimension. something like this `where Country = 'fr'`. I've tried various solution however I'm always stuck with Over clause error or scope error.

Since I want to use this query within Google Data Studio I need to build it with SQL legacy.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I would like to be able to use a where statement based on one of the custom dimension

Below assumes that your query works as you expected so it only addressing "filtering" by country which is essentially the question!

```
SELECT
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 10, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS postId,
  DATE(MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 4, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL))) WITHIN RECORD AS Datepublished,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 1, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Country,
  MAX(IF (hits.customDimensions.index = 7, hits.customDimensions.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS Author,
FROM
  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([storied-toolbox-145015:102152044.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1, 'DAY')))
HAVING Country = 'fr'
```

As you can see the "trick" is in using `HAVING` here instead of `WHERE`